# More efficient way of completing long if-elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

For context I am taking a value from a  html form for prices.
e.g: 0 - any price, 1 = $0 to $100, 2 = $100 to $200 etc.

Surely there must be a more pythonic or efficient way to code such a tedious statement that I am defaulting to right now:

```
  if price_sel == 0:
        min = False
        max = False
    elif price_sel == 1:
        max = 100
    elif price_sel == 2:
        min = 100
        max = 200
    elif price_sel == 3:
etc. etc.
```

Thanks for any input. :)

I have tried searching the web but haven't found any relevent responses.

Comment: A dict or list? A `match..case` statement?

Comment: I recommend that you don't get in the habit of overwriting builtin functions. Obviously not a problem if you don't use those functions, but I've seen lots bugs caused by that.

Comment: Also, I don't know how you use max and min later in your code, but realize that False has the value 0. You probably want to use None instead.

Comment: given the pattern, you could use a single else:  low = 100*(price_sel - 1); high = 100*price_sel

Answer (score 1):

```
price_ranges = {
    0: (None, None),  # any price
    1: (0, 100),
    2: (100, 200),
    # Add more ranges as needed
}

min_price, max_price = price_ranges.get(price_sel, (None, None))
```

In this approach:

price_ranges is a dictionary where the keys are the price_sel values, and the values are tuples containing the minimum and maximum prices for each range.
price_ranges.get(price_sel, (None, None)) retrieves the corresponding tuple of (min, max) values for the given price_sel. If the price_sel is not found in the dictionary, it defaults to (None, None).
You can then use the min_price and max_price variables as needed in your code.
This approach is more concise, easier to maintain, and avoids repetitive conditional statements.

Comment: thats awesome thanks @Deeppp. Out of curiosity, which approach would resolve faster; match - case or dict approach? thanks

Comment: @Prendles Not sure about the speed difference but using a dictionary is superior to *match* because the significant code (that determines the ranges) stays simple and unchanged even if the dictionary has additional key/value pairs added to it. Using *match* you'd have to add more runtime code

Answer (score 0):

If the ranges are multiples of 100 then, for example:

```
def ranges(n):
    return ((n - 1) * 100, n * 100) if n > 0 else (None, None)
    
for n in range(4):
    lo, hi = ranges(n)
    print(f"{n=} {lo=} {hi=}")
```

**Output:**

```
n=0 lo=None hi=None
n=1 lo=0 hi=100
n=2 lo=100 hi=200
n=3 lo=200 hi=300
```